# Differential equation / intermediate value theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$f: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is continuous and $f(t,x)<0$ holds for $tx>0$ and $f(t,x)>0$ holds for $tx<0$

I want  to show, that $x(t)=0 $ is the only solution of $x'=f(t,x)$

You can say, that there is an solution, because f is continuous.
By the intermediate value theorem exists $\xi \in[-a,a] $, such that $f(t, \xi)=0 $.
I only have to show, that $x(t)=0$ is unique. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't think that it is true. Take $f(t,x)=-tx$, then $x'=f(t,x)$ has also a solution $x(t)=e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$.

Comment: Ok then the task might be wrong?

Comment: If there are no other assumptions, then yes, it is wrong.

Comment: Sorry I forgot something: $x(0)=0$

Comment: I'm so sorry for that:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, $x(t)=0$ is one solution. If $x_1(t)$ is another solution, then for $y(t)= x(t)-x_1(t)$ we have $y'(t)=0$, so $y(t)=C$. Since $x(0)=x_1(0)=0$, then $C=y(0)=x(0)-x_1(0)=0$, so $y(t)=0$ and $x_1(t)=x(t)=0$.

Comment: How do you come to $y'=x'-x_1'=x_1'=0$ Why is $x_1'=0$?

Comment: It is not, $y'=x'-x_1'=f-f=0$ by the assumption.

Comment: I see. Where do you use: $f(t,x)<0$ holds for $tx>0$ and $f(t,x)>0$ holds for $tx<0$

Comment: You used it when you concluded that $x(t)=0$ is one solution. :-)

Comment: Ok that was right:) I thought -a refers to tx<0 and a to tx>0. Is that right?

Comment: To prove that $x(t)=0$ is a solution you have to prove that $x'(t)=0=f(t,x)$, i.e. that $f(t,0)=0$ for every $t$. If $t<0$, for every $a>0$ you have $f(t,-a)<0$ and $f(t,a)>0$, so by continuity $f(t,0)=0$. Similarly, $f(t,0)=0$ for $t>0$. Finaly, againg by continuity, $f(0,0)=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help:)